# Traits não aceitam sobrescrita de propriedades?

Tags: php, herança, propriedade, trait

Segundo o trecho do Manual do PHP

> Um Trait destina-se a reduzir algumas limitações de herança simples, permitindo que um desenvolvedor de reutilizar conjuntos de métodos livremente...

Veja um exemplo:

```
trait Stack
{
    protected $items = [];

    public function say()
    {
        return 'stack';
    }

}

class Overflow
{
    use Stack;

    public function stackoverflow()
    {
        return $this->say() . ' overflow';
    }
}

$o = new Overflow;

echo $o->stackoverflow(); // stack overflow
```

No caso acima,importamos o método `say` para a classe `Overflow`.

Também é possível sobrescrever o método do `trait`.

```
    class Overflow
    {
        use Stack;

        public function say()
        {
            return 'overflow';
        }
    }

  echo (new Overflow)->say(); // overflow
```

Porém, quando tento sobrescrever a propriedade `$items` do `trait Stack`, o seguinte erro é gerado.

Exemplo:

```
class Overflow
{
    use Stack;
    protected $items = []; // mesma propriedade de "Stack"
}
```

Erro gerado:

> **Strict Standards**: Overflow and Stack define the same property ($items)
>   in the composition of Overflow. This might be incompatible, to improve
>   maintainability consider using accessor methods in traits instead

Por que não é possível redeclarar uma propriedade em um `Trait`? Isso está fora do objetivo pelo qual ele foi criado?

Comment: Isso não é um erro pois seu código continuará a funcionar sem problemas. 

É só um alerta que você deveria tentar implementar isso de outra forma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso não é um erro, é um aviso.

Um `trait` **pode** inserir propriedades em uma classe. Se uma classe **tem** uma propriedade **idêntica** à do `trait`, você recebe o warn **`Strict Standards`**, caso contrário, você recebe um **erro fatal**.

Informação obtida [deste site](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php).